# Deleting all observations given one observation for each variable's type

Tags: stata

I have a table with firm identifiers, fiscal year, quarter and market_capital. I want to delete all firm observations that had a specific market capital at a specific quarter of a specific year. That is, I want to delete all observations for a firm if its market capital for 2006, quarter 2 was below 50.

My table is in the form:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmspB.jpg)

Comment: Better to edit real(istic) data into question. Images are not so helpful.

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before your next post.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have a *Stata* *dataset* containing four *variables* which I will call firm, year, quarter, and mc (since "Capital Market" shown in the picture of your data is not valid a Stata variable name).

The following code might start you in the right direction, but it is untested since my copy of Stata cannot read the picture of your data, and "I want to retype data from a picture of data" said nobody, ever.

Added in edit: the untested code had an error, so I removed it.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I didn't paste the table. Its my second post in Stackoverflow. I will learn for next time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46638497/replacing-observations-with-a-previous-set-observation didn't have a data example either. Install `dataex` from SSC with `ssc inst dataex` to find how to get data examples that can be copied and pasted into SO.

Answer (score 0):

Having a quarterly date variable -- rather than separate year and quarter variables -- will be needed sooner or later.

That could be

```
gen qdate = yq(year, quarter) 
format qdate %tq
```

Then your code for `drop`ping is

```
egen todrop = total(capital < 50 & qdate == yq(2006, 2)), by(firm)  
drop if todrop
```

as the variable `todrop` will be 1 if and only if you want to `drop` a firm and 0 otherwise.

See [this paper](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0055) for a review of related technique.