# Replacing observations with a previous set observation

Tags: stata

I have three columns. One identifies the observations by F. The other column orders each observation within the same F, called T. The third column is a numerical value, called Q. I'd like all my values for Q greater than a certain value of T to be replaced by the values at a fixed T, within the same F. For example, I'd like all values of Q within the same F that have T > 6 to be equal to whatever value Q has for that F has for T = 6. If an F has a Q value of 40 at T=6 and a Q value of 50 at T=7, I want that Q at T=7 to say 40 as well.

Comment: For Stata questions, please use Stata terminology. You have variables not columns and you want to replace their values. More importantly, examples with explanation always are better than explanation alone.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the correct way of solving this, but it did the trick. If anyone has a better solution, please help me out.

```
xtset F T
gen Q_fixed = Q
replace Q_fixed = . if T > 6
replace Q_fixed = L.Q_fixed if Q_fixed == .
```

Comment: Once `xtset` this telescopes to `gen Q_fixed = cond(T > 6, L.Q, Q)`.